# Return all search hits in the highlighted list in solr using solrnet

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solrnet

We are trying to execute a solr based search on the content of text files and the requirement is trying to return all the hits of the search term in each document along with the highlighted text around the hit.

We are able to return the number of documents found along with the highlighted snippet around the first hit of the search term in the document. But is does not return the list of highlights across the document where the search term is found. We can get the TermFrequency reported as the correct number but not the snippets around all these occurrences.

Relevant portion of the solr schema:

```
<field name="Content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="ContentSearch" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="Content" dest="ContentSearch"/>
```

For example, if we have a.txt and b.pdf which are indexed, and the search term 
"case" exists in both the documents multiple times(a.txt - 7 hits, b.pdf - 10 
hits), when executing a search for "case" against both the documents, we are 
getting two documents returned with the correct term frequencies(7 and 9) but the highlight list contains only one record which corresponds to the first hit in the files.

Is this something to do with using TermVectorComponent for the content field. I have read but could not quite make out the way the TVC works and in which situation it is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the default settings for Highlighting. In order to achieve what you want, I would recommend changing the [snippets](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.snippets) and [maxAnalyzedChars](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.maxAnalyzedChars) options. By default the snippets is set to only return one snippet and maxAnalyzedChars will only look at the first 51200 characters. I would  set these values to `snippets=20`  (or some value larger than the expected max number of snippets) and `maxAnalyzedChars=100000` (or some other value larger than the longest field value) this will ensure that the entire value is analyzed and that all highlights are returned.

Note: You may also need to work with the [fragsize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsizehttp://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsize) setting to get the appropriate size for the snippets (to include the line before and after the highlighted word). As the default size for the fragments is 100 characters.

Within SolrNet you would need to set the `Snippets` and `MaxAnalyzedChars` properties on the `HighlightingParameters` you are passing to your query. Like something similar to the following:

```
   var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("ContentSearch", "case"), 
     new QueryOptions {
       Highlight = new HighlightingParameters {
          Fields = new[] {"ContentSearch"},
          Snippets = 20,
          MaxAnalyzedChars = 100000,
      }
   });
```

Comment: I did the changes as mentioned by you and re-executed the search. Now it is returning the text of the file with all the search terms highlighted. But the original requirement is to return separate highlighted snippets around each occurrence of the search term. For example, with your changes I am getting the highlight count as 1 with all the text returned. what I wanted was to get the highlight count as the no. of matches with each highlight specifying one line above and one line below of the original line where the term occurs. Hope I was able to clearly state the requirement.

Comment: I did this approach and while it is returning the individual snippets around the term, it not returning all the relevant snippets for a fairly large document. I think this is because of the MaxAnalyzedChars setting as this instructs Solr to analyze a maximum of that many characters to figure out the snippets. But for a large file, this setting might not be enough. I specified this value as int32.MaxValue but quite logically it might still be lesser than the number of characters in a large file. Is there a way to specify the highlighter to look at the entire file rather than a fixed value?

Comment: According to this prior issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-610 You can set `maxAnalyzedChars=-1` to instruct Solr to analyze the entire document, regardless of the size. Does that work for you? Optionally, you might check if you are using the regex fragmenter in your highlighter as you may need to set the `hl.regex.maxAnalyzedChars` parameter as well - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.regex.maxAnalyzedChars